# Maven cannot find jars of package shipped as war

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I want to include (import) some classes from an java package that is shipped as a `war` in the maven central repository but also has a `jar` package. Which is why its dependency xml on the [mvn repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.camunda.bpm/camunda-engine-rest/7.14.0) website is stated as

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
    <artifactId>camunda-engine-rest</artifactId>
    <version>7.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I use the dependency in my pom and my code compiles successfully. But when I run `mvn clean install` I get the below error:

```
Failure to find org.camunda.bpm:camunda-engine-rest:jar:7.14.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

Also when I add type `war` (`<type>war</type>`) to my dependency, I dont get the above error but now my code wont compile.

It is strange because when I visit https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 and navigate to the GAV I can find the [jars](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/camunda/bpm/camunda-engine-rest/7.14.0/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JARs in the directory you showed have *classifiers*.

If you need one of them, you must add the classifier to the dependency, e.g.

`<classifier>classes</classifier>`

I don't know Camunda, but I would also look into the documentation. It may be better to use some other approach instead of trying the use a class of a WAR.

Comment: Thanks I was trying that and it worked and I was about to post it as an answer. But I have one final concern that will this take care of the transitive dependencies? Say the newly included classes try to import a package that is not present in my original pom?

Comment: Well I found out that camunda exposes rest pakcages into two other artifacts too (ships them as jar too) so I can use them instead of this. But I will still accept this as a answer as this was the way to go had there been no other packages

Comment: This should also work with transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

problem using pure spring boot "starter" dependencies that it contains camunda engine plus tomcat, so even when you remove tomcat using either  or , it continues to run on tomcat as its already with in camunda engine. And when you try to create war file and paste in into shared camunda engine outside then that war will no work. This is because that war you created containing camunda engine and a tomcat inside it and when you paste into another outside camunda engine, it gets confused to which camunda to use.
See this solution : http://javaint4bytes.blogspot.com/2019/11/camunda-spring-boot-with-shared-engine.html

Answer (score 0):

A possibly better approach would be to not reference the complete WAR as a dependency but the specific jars you need from it. You can add the jars you are importing from in your code (e.g. camunda-engine) to your POM instead of the complete war file. Here is an example: https://github.com/rob2universe/camunda-custom-rest-endpoint/blob/main/custom-endpoint/pom.xml